# Can I scroll back to the top of an element in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, js-scrollintoview

I am using accordions, and after I open an accordion, I use `scrollIntoView` to bring the window to the center of the accordion. When I close the accordion, I want to use `scrollIntoView` to bring the top of the windows screen to the top of the accordion elements parent element. I can identify the parent element fine, but for some reason `scrollIntoView` is not working. Here is the JavaScript I am using:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  var reply_click = function() {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      var relevant = document.getElementById(this.id);
      var scrBack = relevant.parentElement.parentElement.id;
      console.log(scrBack);

      if (content.style.display === "block") {
        content.style.display = "none";
        scrBack.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "smooth",
          block: "end",
          inline: "nearest"
        });
      } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
        relevant.scrollIntoView({
          block: 'start',
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
      }
    });

    reply_click();
  }
}
```

I would like to do this without the use of jQuery.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there an error whenever you call `scrollINtoView()`?

Comment: There is no error, it just does not execute the command. It executes relevant.scrollIntoView(); just fine though, so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Try calling the `scrBack.scrollIntoView` with it's options in DevTools... and see what it returns